# Asking for authentication for update the system

Tags: release-loki, elementary-website

every time I start my notebook after suspend appear about 6 posters asking for authentication for update the system, as in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its an appcenter bug. I don't know of a fix, but you can run:
killall appcenter

stops appcenter from running in the background. Then suspend your notebook and wake it back up. Problem should be gone, but will come back when appcenter is run or you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

So I just update appcenter to version 0.1.2 that was released today. So far it's working ok. Thanks for the replys.